# PHP: posting data to REST API (Sorenson 360)

Tags: php, rest, curl, sorenson-360

I've tried using this to login to the sorenson 360 API:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$username = "<username>";
$password = "<password>";
define('POSTURL','https://360services.sorensonmedia.com/sessions');
define('POSTVARS','username=$username&password=$password');

$c = curl_init(POSTURL);
var_dump($c);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,POSTVARS);
$content = curl_exec($c);

var_dump($content);

curl_close($c);
```

And this is what i see in the browser:

```
resource(1) of type (curl) bool(false)
```

Here is the link for the API method: http://developers.sorensonmedia.com/api/accounts/login

Can anyone please explain to me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never liked cURL. Why don't you try a more fully featured HTTP client like [Zend_Rest_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.client.html) or the more bare bones, [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html)

Comment: this is on a shared host, and Zend is not installed and i have no access to install anything... :(

Comment: The Zend Framework is simply a bunch of PHP files. You can install the entire framework or just the components you need (and their dependencies) by uploading the files to your site.

Comment: following your suggestion, i uploaded the Zend files, and used the Zend_Rest_Client, and after some trial and error, was able to get the data i need. thanks.