# Sorenson 360 API call with cURL+PHP returning false

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, curl, sorenson-360

I'm trying to access the Sorenson-360 API with cURL and PHP, however I am not able to authenticate with their API.

The code I'm using is:

```
$postURL = "https://360services.sorensonmedia.com/sessions";
$postVars = "username=".$username."&password=".$password;
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);
var_dump($c);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);
$content = curl_exec($c);
var_dump($content);
//echo $content;
curl_close($c);
```

My response printed out on the page is:

> resource(4) of type (curl) string(1) " "

The API documention I am trying to use is here:
http://developers.sorensonmedia.com/api/accounts/login

A similar post on StackOverflow that yeilded no solution other than to use zend (which I don't have nor understand) was posted here:
[PHP: posting data to REST API (Sorenson 360)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151104/php-posting-data-to-rest-api-sorenson-360)

I don't have access to install anything on my server and the Zend getting started documentation is not clicking with me. I would prefer to use cURL for this as I'm somewhat familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several problems in your code:

1. in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, POSTURL);` you should change `$ch` variable to `$c`
2. security certificate of the site you're connecting to is not trusted. To disable this check you need to add `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`
3. finally, why do you need to define constants for url and post parameters? What's wrong with good old PHP variables?

**Upd:**

For debugging purposes, I suggest that you turn on the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

If you get `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` for response, something is wrong with the service you're calling, not with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I am still not able to successfully connect to their API. The new code and error in the first post

Comment: Adding the header information showed a 500 Internal Server Error... I forwarded it to their engineering dept. who I've been in contact with to get it resolved. Thank you for your help.